# Azure - Bot Channels Registration setup changed, Connections are removed

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-rm-template, azure-bot-service

This morning I noticed that the setup of the Bot Channels Registrations has been changed, which is no problem, the issue is that the connections are removed.

Before there was an Active Directory V2 connection, which has suddenly disappeared. All I can see now is "No Settings defined"
[image]

All bots lose authentication now. What is happening here, is this a planned upgrade, is this a known issue?

Update: Running the pipeline now to deploy the BCR again also fails. It hangs for 1 hour on the BCR ARM template and then cancels
[image]

Comment: There was definitely some upgrade to Bot Service/Bot Channel Registration overnight. You will probably have better luck opening a ticket with Azure Support since this isn't really a programming issue.

Comment: @billoverton Thanks, good to hear your observation, that's valuable info.. We submitted a ticket as well.

Comment: @Bastiaan, is your issue resolved?